# How to build dynamic query (IN clause) using expression

Tags: c#, sql, entity, expression

I have

```
<!-- language: c# -->
   Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>
```

that consists of properties

- StartDate datetime
- EndDate datetime
- ShowArticles bool
- ShowMaterials bool
- ShowProducts bool

I want to build dynamic query which will look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Docs
WHERE StartDate >= @StartDAte 
AND EndDate <= @EndDAte 
AND ArticleInternalType IN (1,2,3)
```

All bool types are bounded to checkboxes (Checked).
If user uncheck checkbox query should also be changed. Example if user unchecked ShowMaterials checkbox:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Docs
WHERE StartDate >= @StartDate 
AND EndDate <= @EndDAte 
AND ArticleInternalType IN (1,3)
```

This expression gives awkward result

```
FilterExpression =
f => f.DocumentDate >= StartDate.Date && f.DocumentDate <= EndDate.Date
&& (
showArticles == true ? f.ArticleInternalType == 1 : f.ArticleInternalType == -1 ||
showMaterials == true ? f.ArticleInternalType == 0 : f.ArticleInternalType == -1 ||
showProducts == true ? f.ArticleInternalType == 2 : f.ArticleInternalType == -1
);
```

Here is result from SQLProfiler

```
WHERE 
([Extent1].[DocumentDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[DocumentDate] <= @p__linq__1) 
AND 
((CASE WHEN (1 = @p__linq__2) THEN 
        CASE WHEN (1 = [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(1 as bit) 
             WHEN (1 <> [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(0 as bit) 
        END 
        WHEN (1 = @p__linq__3) THEN 
        CASE WHEN (2 = [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(1 as bit) 
            WHEN (2 <> [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(0 as bit) 
        END 
        WHEN (1 = @p__linq__4) THEN 
        CASE WHEN (3 = [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(1 as bit) 
            WHEN (3 <> [Extent1].[ArticleInternalType]) 
                THEN cast(0 as bit) 
        END 
    ELSE cast(0 as bit) 
END) = 1)
```

Can someone give me advice, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it using a list of `int` types:

```
var types = new List<int>();
if (showArticles) types.Add(1);
if (showMaterials) types.Add(0);
if (showProducts) types.Add(2);
FilterExpression = f => f.DocumentDate >= StartDate.Date
    && f.DocumentDate <= EndDate.Date
    && types.Contains(f. ArticleInternalType);
```

You could also simplify the expression that you wrote:

```
FilterExpression =
f => f.DocumentDate >= StartDate.Date && f.DocumentDate <= EndDate.Date
&& (
    showArticles && f.ArticleInternalType == 1
||  showMaterials && f.ArticleInternalType == 0 
||  showProducts && f.ArticleInternalType == 2
);
```